# Is there a keyboard shortcut to maximize the Game window in Unity in Play Mode?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> maximizes most windows in unity 2018 when in edit mode. Is there a keyboard shortcut to maximize the Game window when you're playing your game?

Can't find anything in the docs.

Comment: Go to Game tab and toggle Maximize On Play. But if you are talking about zooming in and out in that case you have to attach script to your camera with instructions.

Comment: On Mac is Shift + Ctrl + Space

Comment: @[Ethan Fischer] Your answer using the static class works well. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Created a script to do the job that doesn't need to be attached to a gameobject:

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[InitializeOnLoad]
static class FullscreenShortcut
{
    static FullscreenShortcut()
    {
        EditorApplication.update += Update;
    }

    static void Update()
    {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        if (EditorApplication.isPlaying && ShouldToggleMaximize())
        {
            EditorWindow.focusedWindow.maximized = !EditorWindow.focusedWindow.maximized;
        }
#endif
    }

    private static bool ShouldToggleMaximize()
    {
        return Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice. Only thing is if you hold down shift you can only press space once to toggle. For some reason if you hit space again it doesn't toggle back.

Answer (score 14):

You can implement it yourself.

```
    void Update()
    {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            UnityEditor.EditorWindow.focusedWindow.maximized = !UnityEditor.EditorWindow.focusedWindow.maximized;
        }   
#endif
    }
```

Comment: Any way for this to work without having to add it to a gameobject in my scene?

Comment: I don't think so.  I'm pretty sure the reason why these other hotkey answers don't reliably work is because the editor doesn't get input when the game window has focus.  So, that rules out editor extensions for the same reason.

Comment: Figured out a way to do it. Submitted it as my answer below. Thanks for getting me going in the right direction!

Answer (score 10):

I think you are able to maximize the windows if it's docked, for floating Windows it shall not work. but you can try (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>) or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Hope it helps you and have a nice day.

Answer (score 3):

A little simpler than Update

```
static class FullscreenShortcut
{
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    [UnityEditor.MenuItem("Window/MaximizeCurrentWindow _F11")]
    static void ToggleCurrentWindowMaximized()
    {
        var window = UnityEditor.EditorWindow.focusedWindow;
        if (window == null)
            return;
        window.maximized = !window.maximized;
    }
#endif
}
```

there is a little more info about MenuItem:
https://hugecalf-studios.github.io/unity-lessons/lessons/editor/menuitem/

just add at the end of MenuItem text

| Symbol | Keyboard Key |
| --- | --- |
| % | Ctrl/Command |
| # | Shift |
| & | Alt |
| _ | None |

with

| Special Key | Keyboard Key |
| --- | --- |
| A-Z | Letters A-Z |
| LEFT, RIGHT, UP, DOWN | Arrow Keys |
| F1-F12 | F1-F12 |
| HOME | Home |
| END | End |
| PGUP | Page Up |
| PGDN | Page Down |

Answer (score 0):

Click this button on the game scene "Maximize On Play" once and you never need to do use short keys again because it repeats itself until you turn it off. IF you still need it on urgent basis you can simply click on the screen and use the (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>) because it is used to maximize any window you are currently working on whether it game screen or any Hierarchy portion.

Comment: Thanks but looking for a keyboard shortcut only. And as mentioned, shift + space doesn't work in play mode

Comment: Yes, it work only in normal way . Actually it is use to maximize your current window you are being working on .

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer of @Ethan Fischer I created the following script which utilizes the new Input System and adds an extra condition.

In playmode the editor still accepts SHIFT+SPACE input for all editor windows except for the game view. This script uses Reflection to get the type of the GameView and compares it to the currently focused window (I observed weird behavior without this check)

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[InitializeOnLoad]
public class MaximizeWhilePlaymode {

#if UNITY_EDITOR

    private static InputEditor input;
    private static float shift;

    static MaximizeWhilePlaymode() {
        input = new InputEditor();
        input.Editor.Enable();
        input.Editor.LeftShift.performed += ctx => shift = ctx.ReadValue<float>();
        input.Editor.Space.performed += ctx => Work(ctx.ReadValue<float>());
    }


    private static void Work(float space) {
        if(Application.isPlaying && shift > 0.5f && space > 0.5f) {
            Assembly assembly = typeof(EditorWindow).Assembly;
            Type type = assembly.GetType("UnityEditor.GameView");

            if(EditorWindow.focusedWindow.GetType() == type) {
                EditorWindow.focusedWindow.maximized = !EditorWindow.focusedWindow.maximized;
            }
        }
    }
#endif

}
```

Answer (score -1):

If the game is already built, try pressing Alt + Enter.

Comment: Sir, please include any reference that you may have. one more thing is that please keep the question in mind. it's about the unity editor not the for the build. even though the answer is right for other scenarios but now for this.

Comment: I know that it's not the answer to the specific question, it's just that that was the answer I was looking for and the question was close enough, so if someone else was looking for that answer I put it there.

Answer (score -1):

Not a shortcut, but you can switch Max/Normal size while in game mode when you click on the tiny menu button on top right corner (then toggle the Maximize option).